# Where on android.git.kernel.org can I find the source for such classes as Activity, Intent, and ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-contentprovider

Not sure how to figure out which android project on android.git.kernel.org corresponds to the classes extended in some of the app examples in the SDK such as Activity, Intent, and ContentProvider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the tree of your desired release under [platform/frameworks/base.git] ,
then

/ core / java / android / app for Activity

/ core / java / android / content for Intent and ContentProvider

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.
FYI for anyone else looking for the same, here's the location for froyo-release:
http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/froyo-release;hb=froyo-release